# Shall I SET STORAGE PLAIN on fixed-length bytea PK column?

Tags: postgresql, performance, join, storage, primary-key

My Postgres table's primary key is a SHA1 checksum (always 20 bytes) stored in a `bytea` column (because Postgres doesn't have fixed-length binary types).

Shall I `ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN c SET STORAGE PLAIN` not to let Postgres compress and/or outsource (TOAST) my PK/FK for the sake of lookup and join performance? And why (not)?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that that is a micro-optimization that will probably not have a measurable effect.

First, PostgreSQL only considers compressing and slicing values if the row exceeds 2000 bytes, so there will only be an effect at all if your rows routinely exceed that size.

Then, even if the primary key column gets toasted, you will probably only be able to measure a difference if you select a large number of rows in a single table scan. Fetching only a few rows by index won't make a big difference.

I'd benchmark both approaches, but I'd assume that it will be hard to measure a difference. I/O and other costs will probably hide the small extra CPU time required for decompression (remember that the row has to be large for TOAST to kick in in the first place).